# Extracting arguments from kwargs in boost::python

Tags: c++, python, boost-python, keyword-argument

I have a C++ class that I'm building into a python module using boost::python. I have a few functions that I want to take keyword arguments. I've set up wrapper functions to pass to raw_arguments and that works fine, but I want to build in some error checking for the function arguments. Is there a standard way to do this?

My function prototype, in C++, looks a bit like this:

```
double MyClass::myFunction(int a, int b, int c);
```

The third argument is optional, with a default value of 0 (I've implemented this in boost::python using macros up till now). In python, I want to be able to achieve the following behaviour:

```
MyClass.my_function(1) # Raises exception
MyClass.my_function(2, 3) # So that a = 2, b = 3 and c defaults to 0
MyClass.my_function(2, 3, 1) # As above, but now c = 1
MyClass.my_function(2, 3, 1, 3) # Raises exception
MyClass.my_function(3, 1, c = 2) # So a = 3, b = 1 and c = 2
MyClass.my_function(a = 2, b = 2, c = 3) # Speaks for itself
MyClass.my_function(b = 2, c = 1) # Raises exception
```

Is there something in boost::python or the raw_function wrapper that can facilitate this, or do I need to write the code to check all this myself? If I do need to, how can I raise the exceptions? Is there a standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [`boost/python/args.hpp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/python/doc/v2/args.html) file provides a family of classes for specifying argument keywords.  In particular, Boost.Python provides an [`arg`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/python/doc/v2/args.html#arg-spec) type, that represents a potential keyword argument.  It overloads the comma operator to allow for a more natural definition of an argument list.

Exposing `myFunction` on `MyClass` as `my_function`, where `a`, `b`, and `c` are keyword arguments, and `c` has a default value of `0` could be written as follows:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::class_<MyClass>("MyClass")
    .def("my_function", &MyClass::myFunction,
         (python::arg("a"), "b", python::arg("c")=0))
    ;
}
```

---

Here is a complete example:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

class MyClass
{
public:
  double myFunction(int a, int b, int c)
  {
    return a + b + c;
  }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::class_<MyClass>("MyClass")
    .def("my_function", &MyClass::myFunction,
         (python::arg("a"), "b", python::arg("c")=0))
    ;
}
```

Interactive Usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> my_class = example.MyClass()
>>> my_class.my_function(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    MyClass.my_function(MyClass, int)
did not match C++ signature:
    my_function(MyClass {lvalue}, int a, int b, int c=0)
>>> assert(5 == my_class.my_function(2, 3))
>>> assert(6 == my_class.my_function(2, 3, 1))
>>> my_class.my_function(2, 3, 1, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    MyClass.my_function(MyClass, int, int, int, int)
did not match C++ signature:
    my_function(MyClass {lvalue}, int a, int b, int c=0)
>>> assert(6 == my_class.my_function(3, 1, c=2))
>>> assert(7 == my_class.my_function(a=2, b=2, c=3))
>>> my_class.my_function(b=2, c=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    MyClass.my_function(MyClass)
did not match C++ signature:
    my_function(MyClass {lvalue}, int a, int b, int c=0)
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, and it's slightly embarrassing that I'd unwittingly used a similar setup on another function to overload that function's arguments. Does this work for constructors too?

Comment: To answer my own question: yes it does. Do py::init<List your argument types>( (py::arg("a"), py::arg("b")...) ) in the wrapper code class declaration.

Comment: (If anyone has trouble making this work, note the additional parenthesis surrounding the args)

Comment: In your example named arguments are always in the same 'natural' order (a,b,c). I guess this should also work: assert(6 == my_class.my_function(c=3, a=2, b=1)), right?